# Woocommerce - Changing 2 Checkout label text does not work

Tags: php, woocommerce

In the checkout page of Woocommerce, I've tried to change the labels of "Billing details" and "Ship to a different address?" into other text but when I input 2 similar codes as below, it only changes once: the "Billing details" did change into "Your billing info" but the "Ship to different address" did not.
Please help.

```
//Change the Billing Address checkout label
function wc_billing_field_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Billing details' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Your billing info', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'wc_billing_field_strings', 20, 3 );

function shipchange( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Ship to a different address?' :
            $translated_text = __( 'other shipping address?', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Any methods on how to change all labels' text in Cart and Checkout pages Woocommerce?

Comment: Yep, looks like you only added filter for first function. You can add a filter for second function or combine two functions into one, as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
function wc_billing_field_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Billing details' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Your billing info', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
        case 'Ship to a different address?' :
            $translated_text = __( 'other shipping address?', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wc_billing_field_strings', 20, 3 );
```